# How to move dependency out of vendor in symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have "inherited" a project that has a git dependency I do not have access to. I have the contents of the whole `/vendor` directory and want to move the dependency out of it so that I do not need to commit the whole `/vendor` directory to git. I have moved the directory with the dependency to `/my-vendor` directory (at the same level as vendor), but have no idea how to include it into the project.
When running `composer install` I get:

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                  
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                                           
  Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "MY_BUNDLE_CLASS" from namespace "DEP_NAME\MY_BUNDLE".                                
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /app/app/AppKernel.php:40                                                                                                                
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                        
  #0 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(406): AppKernel->registerBundles()                                                                                       
  #1 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(113): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()                                                           
  #2 /app/app/AppKernel.php(21): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()                                                                                                                          
  #3 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(137): AppKernel->boot()                                                                                   
  #4 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()                              
  #5 /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(89): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->add(Object(Symfony\Component\Console in /app/app/AppKernel.   
  php on line 40
```

`MY_BUNDLE_CLASS, DEP_NAME, and MY_BUNDLE` being edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can place those bundles in `bundle` directory, for example, and then add to `composer.json` following lines:

```
"repositories": [
  {
      "type" : "path",
      "url" : "./bundles/your-bundle"
  }
]
```